# I get an error with my PHP

Tags: php, html, sql, database, forms

When I sign up on my form, I get this error. Any help would be great.

Error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or 
T_NUM_STRING in /home/u378761662/public_html/action.php on line 3
```

My PHP:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("myhost.com","user","password","db");
$sql="INSERT INTO users values ($_POST["username"], $_POST["pwd"], $_POST["email"])";
if (mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
echo "User added!";
}
```

My HTML:

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
  Username<input type="text" name="username">
  <p>
    Password<input type="password" name="pwd">
    <p>
      Email<input type="text" name="Email">
<p>
    <input type="submit" name="Sign Up" value="Sign Up">
</form>
```

Comment: FYI, you are also wide open to [SQL injections](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)

Comment: You need to filter input.The way you storing the values they are not secure.Just look you form input field name of email is 'Email' and you are trying to get as 'email'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should develop the habit of using query parameters for dynamic values you want to include in SQL queries. This helps to avoid confusion about quotes, and it helps to avoid security vulnerabilities.

It's easy too!

```
$sql="INSERT INTO users values (?, ?, ?)";
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,$sql)) {
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", 
    $_POST["username"], $_POST["pwd"], $_POST["Email"]);
  if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
    echo "User added!";
  }
}
```

PS: [You're Probably Storing Passwords Incorrectly](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help! Now I don't get an error when I sign up, but the stuff inserted into the form doesn't show up in the database. Any suggestions?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out

Comment: Bill did you see the input field name is 'Email' and you are getting as 'email'

Comment: @amarjitsngh I just noticed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's a quoting problem:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO users values ($_POST['username'], $_POST['pwd'], $_POST['email'])";
```

The original `"`s were causing parser errors. Also, as @JohnConde points out, this is "wide open to [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)."

Answer (score 0):

**Warning**: You're still vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/). Check out Bill Karwin's answer for a solution to your issue as well as a way to keep yourself from being vulnerable to these types of attacks.

As the error says, check out line 3, your quotes are awry:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO users values (" . $_POST["username"] . ", " . $_POST["pwd"] . ", " . $_POST["email"] . ")";
```